# Unable to provide values for configurables in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, configurable

I am encountering an issue while trying to provide values for configurable defined in the `email_sender` module of the `github_stats_per_person` package. The configurable include `ClientId`, `ClientSecret`, and `RefreshToken`.

I have added values for configurable in the following format, in Config.toml:

```
[github_stats_per_person.email_sender]
ClientId = ""
ClientSecret = ""
RefreshToken = ""
```

I am encountering the following errors:

```
github_stats_per_person.email_sender
error: value not provided for required configurable variable 'ClientId'
        at wso2/github_stats_per_person.email_sender:0.1.0(configurables.bal:1)
error: value not provided for required configurable variable 'ClientSecret'
        at wso2/github_stats_per_person.email_sender:0.1.0(configurables.bal:2)
error: value not provided for required configurable variable 'RefreshToken'
        at wso2/github_stats_per_person.email_sender:0.1.0(configurables.bal:3)
```

I appreciate any guidance to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

The issue arose from attempting to execute the `bal test` command without including values in the `Config.toml` file located inside the tests' folder. Initially, the configuration only included values in the `Config.toml` file at the root directory.

To resolve this, a dedicated `Config.toml` file was added inside the `tests` folder with the necessary values for configurable, such as `ClientId`, `ClientSecret`, and `RefreshToken`.